# How to validate a string entered in the input box against an excel range which contains that string?

Tags: excel, vba

Please excuse me for this question as I'm a novice. I'm trying to enter a string in the VBA inputbox and take that string and validate against a range containing a list of strings in an excel sheet("Roles"). If the string is present in the range, then I would like to display the value in the next column using Vlookup and display that in a msg box. Otherwise I would like to have a msgbox displaying the "string doesn't exist". I have the below code which I can't get it to work. When I execute the code,I get a type mismatch error Highly appreciate your help !

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetRoles()
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Role As String

    Name = InputBox("Enter a Name")
    Sheets("Roles").Activate

    If Range("name_list").Value = Name Then
        Role = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Name, Range("name_list"), 2, False)
        MsgBox Name & " is a " & Role
    Else
        MsgBox Name & " does not exist"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should state which line errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in this line

```
If Range("name_list").Value = Name Then
```

you are trying to check the existence of a value in a multi-cell range and you can't do this, not without a loop through each cell or a different approach.

This is one such approach, using the Find method.

```
Sub GetRoles()

Dim Name As String
Dim Role As String
Dim r As Range

Name = InputBox("Enter a Name")
If Name = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Sheets("Roles").Activate
Set r = Range("name_list").Find(What:=Name, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If r Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox Name & " does not exist"
Else
    MsgBox Name & " is a " & r.Offset(, 2).Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfect.